# UITableView setEditing stretches part of cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, drawrect

Ran into a weird issue with drawn UITableViewCell.

When I setEditing for a UITableView, a UIImage I am drawing on the right side it stretched during the animation. The graphic draws correctly and in the correct spots both in and out of editing, but when animating either with a swipe to delete or setEditing, that part of the UITableViewCell stretches, and it looks ugly.

Here's a screen capture about halfway through the setEditing animation:

[image: Weird UITableViewCell stretching]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have the content view's autoresize masking set to flexible width

Comment: It's not and still does it. Even set it to UIViewAutoresizingNone and it still stretches when redrawing.

Comment: You may need to set the autoresizingMask for the UIImageView (not the contentView) to UIViewAutoresizingNone.